# How to run an awk command?

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to learn how to calculate polygenic risk scores and I am following a step-by-step tutorial (this one: https://choishingwan.github.io/PRS-Tutorial/plink/). However, I have been stuck trying to figure out how to run this command:

```
awk 'NR!=1{print $3}' EUR.clumped >  EUR.valid.snp
```

Obviously, this is not something I can make run in R, but apparently by using `system()`, people said it should work. But it doesn't. I then tried to run this command in my own Windows command prompt but it doesn't recognize `awk` as an intern command.

I then tried to maybe update my command prompt with `wsl --install` (because that's the only conclusion I could come up to) but apparently my administrator account needs permission to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you could mention a couple of things:
Does R give you an error?

I assume you are trying to run it on a linux system with awk installed?
To check if awk is installed, try running this in your linux terminal:

```
which awk
```

To run your awk command from within R, you should escape the ' characters with a \ in your awk command, and put the entire command within quotes:

```
system('awk \'NR!=1{print $3}\' EUR.clumped > EUR.valid.snp')
```

Comment: I am trying to run it in my windows 10 command prompt (which I assume is a linux system) however it tells me awk is not recognize as an intern command. 

To see if awk is installed I tried to use which aswell, however which is also not recognize. 
I assume awk is probably not installed along with a bunch of other packages but I have no idea how to install them.

The command on R gives me a 127 error. I guess since nothing is installed, the command can't be called.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The windows command prompt is not linux.
However, you mentioned installing wsl (windows subsystem for linux). You should see this as a completely separate operating system installed on the same PC. In WSL you should be able to install AWK, R etc.

Comment: In the tutorial you're following it's assumed that you have a minimal knowledge about how to work with linux terminal and some other tools. 
On their homepage they provide some useful links to learn all this. I would highly recommend you to do so if you plan on doing analyses like these!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations 
I am still quite lost but I ll do more research then. Have a nice day!